# Cannot login to Kibana via Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cognito

I've deployed Amazon Elasticsearch with Cognito as the auth provider. I'm receiving an error when I try to login to Kibana.

I can sign up and do receive the verification code but when I enter it to try and confirm I get an error page.

[image]

I'm using Terraform and was able to run my code multiple times with it working but something changed and now the authentication between Kibana and Cognito is failing. I noticed that my user **does** get added to the User Pool but an identity for it doesn't show up in the Identity Pool Console.

The access Policy on the Elasticsearch node looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my_account_id>:role/Cognito-<identity_pool_name>-Auth-Role"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttp*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:<my_account_id>:domain/<elasticsearch_domain_name>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Authenticated Role from above, i.e. `"arn:aws:iam::<my_account_id>:role/Cognito-<identity_pool_name>-Auth-Role"` has this policy attached to it which gives the identity pool access to Kibana.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "cognito-identity:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated!